# iOS 13 SIGABRT in com.apple.root.default-qos

Tags: ios, xcode

An app that ran fine under iOS 12 crashes on startup under iOS 13.  The thread "com.apple.root.default-qos" throws a SIGABRT.  I can't find any useful information in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13, new requirements for bluetooth permissions were put into place.  Even if your app doesn't use Bluetooth, you may include a library that contains references to Core Bluetooth libraries.  In this case you'll need to ask your user for permission to use Bluetooth, even if you don't need the permission, or your app will crash.

Simply add a Usage Description for the Bluetooth permissions into your Info.plist file.  The key is NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription.  I also define NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription for backward compatibility with iOS12 and earlier.  It looks like this in XCode:

[image]

Note that if you don't need the Bluetooth permission the user can choose "Don't Allow" and feel more comfortable.  As you can see above, I actually make this clear to the user in my Usage Description.